# cast to List after deserialization (generics)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List that is binaryserialized to a file, but when I an going to deserialize the file I get the compilation error below:

I am nor particulary familiar with casting generics between different classes.

*The type arguments for method 'UtilitiesLibrary.BinSerialization.BinaryFileDeserialize(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

Code

```
//Class myManager
public void DeserializeAnimals(string filePath)
{
  m_animalList = (List<Animal>) BinSerialization.BinaryFileDeserialize(filePath);
}


//Class BinSerializer
public static T BinaryFileDeserialize<T>(string filename)
{
  T objectSerialize;
  Stream stream = null;

try
{
  stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
  BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  objectSerialize = (T)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException) { objectSerialize = default(T); }
finally
{
if (stream != null)
  stream.Close();
}

  return objectSerialize;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need:

```
m_animalList = BinSerialization.BinaryFileDeserialize<List<Animal>>(filePath);
```

Generics can be inferred from *arguments*, but not from *return-values*. Which is why a similar method:

```
void Serialize<T>(string filePath, T value)
```

can be called as

```
Serialize(path, m_animalList);
```

since here the type of `m_animalList` (known by the compiler) can help resolve the `T`. The above line is 100% identical (in this case) to:

```
Serialize<List<Animal>>(path, m_animalList);
```

I will also, however, warn that `BinaryFormatter` might bite you down the road - it is *not* very version-tolerant.

Comment: @user601496 please, please note the warning in the last line, though ;p

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in this lin, it should be:

```
public void DeserializeAnimals(string filePath) 
{   
    m_animalList = BinSerialization.BinaryFileDeserialize<List<Animal>>(filePath); 
}
```